# Exception while connecting to RPC when using the Corda 3 node driver

Tags: corda

When I run Corda 3 nodes using the node driver, I intermittently get the following exception:

```
[INFO ] 15:09:20,485 [driver-pool-thread-0] (DriverDSLImpl.kt:169) internal.DriverDSLImpl.invoke - Exception while connecting to RPC, retrying to connect at localhost:10013 {}
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:787) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:191) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:123) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:86) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:191) ~[corda-core-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:109) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:135) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:120) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:166) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:82) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$poll$task$1.run(InternalTestUtils.kt:86) [corda-node-driver-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
[INFO ] 15:09:20,469 [driver-pool-thread-1] (DriverDSLImpl.kt:169) internal.DriverDSLImpl.invoke - Exception while connecting to RPC, retrying to connect at localhost:10010 {}
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:787) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:191) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:123) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:86) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
```

What can I do to fix this? It doesn't happen every time I start the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the node driver sometimes does not shut down the node processes cleanly. You need to kill any lingering Java processes before running the node driver again.

On osX, you can do this by running:

```
killall java -9
```

On Windows, you can do this by running:

```
wmic process where "name like '%java%'" delete
```