# Corda node AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers

Tags: corda, activemq-artemis, cordite

For my dev env I'm running a [network-map-service](https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service) to which I register my corda node. The problem is that it fails to start with following error.

```
E 07:21:44+0000 [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup {}
 org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:787) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.ArtemisMessagingClient.start(ArtemisMessagingClient.kt:39) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RPCMessagingClient.start(RPCMessagingClient.kt:19) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.Node.startMessagingService(Node.kt:306) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:255) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$start$4.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:685) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$initialiseDatabasePersistence$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:105) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:152) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:138) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:124) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:131) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:684) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.Node.initialiseDatabasePersistence(Node.kt:345) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:206) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:359) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:145) ~[corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:115) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13) [corda-node-3.2-corda.jar:?]
```

I'm not really sure to which servers does it refer to, as obviously there are no other servers in network map yet. It looks like it might be related to ActiveMQ Artemis internally, but I'm not sure of that.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: is this error you get when you start your node or the network map? if the node, then check on the network map url and is it accessible ?  also is the db configured correctly?

Comment: it from corda nodestartup as you can see by the fact that it relates to `net.corda.node.internal`. What I need to understand is what does this error really mean... cause it looks like artemis issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by zombie Java processes. Try killing them using the commands listed here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49425918/4620025) and running the network map server again.

Comment: that is definately not the case here